# Generate unique list and count with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

How to list all the names of a column in a unique way and add the corresponding value (of each cell with similar name)?

**Example**

column A: name | column B: value

[image: column A: name | column B: value]

result: column D and E

[image: result: column D and E]

Comment: Use a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using multiple sheets, then try this,

STEP 1 :Copy all the values of Column A to the next sheet and use `Remove Duplicates` function.
STEP 2 :Use the `SUMIF()` function to get the sum of all the values of Column B respective to Column A.

Else, you can follow the question here [Copy Only Unique Values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50273551/9600315)

Hope, this helps.